# Largest media query (min-width:1020px) keeps overriding smallest media query's (max-width:599px) flex-direction value

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, media-queries

I have 4 media queries in this order in my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px)
@media screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width: 895px)
@media screen and (min-width: 896px) and (max-width: 1019px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1020px)
```

They work mostly, except for when I try to change flex-direction. I have this class above the media queries:

```
.home-mod4-founders {
 display:flex;
 align-items:stretch;
}
```

And this under the smallest media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
 .home-mod4-founders {
  flex-direction:column;
 }
}
```

For some reason, when the screen is under 599px, it takes on the value of one of the other 3 queries:

```
.home-mod4-founders {
 flex-direction:row;
}
```

When I checked the page with Chrome's dev tools, it seemed to strip out the media query part of the largest one so that it overrides the 599px media query:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crN3u.png)
The live site is here: www.whisperlodge.nyc

And I copy-pasted the CSS and HTML into a codepen http://codepen.io/chillinkwa/pen/MJZVEj

Comment: When you change `flex-direction`, `align-items: stretch` no longer applies to the cross axis. Instead, it applies to the main axis for `flex-direction: column`. Without looking at the code in full, it is hard to tell what is wrong though.

Comment: Ok just signed up for Codepen and stuck my CSS and HTML in a pen:
http://codepen.io/chillinkwa/pen/MJZVEj

If anything looks off in the pen, it might be because it's wordpress.com specific. The live site is also at www.whisperlodge.nyc

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by deleting the class from that largest media query. As the same specifications exist in the one below that, they somehow still seem to apply at a large browser width.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999830/using-multiple-css-media-queries-but-its-only-using-the-largest-one/43999854#43999854